# Use a specific map in angular2-highmaps and angular-cli

Tags: angular, highcharts, highmaps

I am trying to use Highmaps in an angular-cli app with angular2-highcharts package.

I want to use a specific map (http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js) that I saved into my `assets/map` directory, and linked in `.angular-cli.json` (apps[0].scripts).

**NgModule**

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
...
imports: [
  ChartModule.forRoot(
    require('highcharts/highmaps'),
  ),
}
```

**component.ts**:

```
    const Highcharts = require('highcharts');

    this.mapOptions = {
      title: {
        text: 'Zoom in on country by double click',
      },

      mapNavigation: {
        enabled: false,
        enableDoubleClickZoomTo: true
      },

      colorAxis: {
        min: 1,
        max: 1000,
        type: 'logarithmic',
      },

      series: [{
        data: data.audience.distributionByCountry,
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
        joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
        name: 'Population density',
        states: {
          hover: {
            color: '#a4edba',
          },
        },
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: '/km²',
        },
      }],
    };
```

**html**

**The error (generated by Angular's `addScript.js`) complains that the Highcharts is not defined.**

Out of curiosity I tried to add the following:

```
Highcharts = Highcharts || {maps: {}};
```

at the beginning of the map file so see if that was the problem, but it didn't solve the case.

What should I do to get the locally saved map to work?

### EDIT

**Detailed attempt report**

*Attempt 1*

**@NgModule**

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';

declare const Highcharts: any;
require('highcharts/modules/map')(Highcharts);

import '../../assets/maps/world.js';
...
imports: [
  ChartModule.forRoot(
    Highcharts,
  ),
]
```

Compile error

Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'Highcharts'. Consider exporting the symbol (position 21:15 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol InsightsModule in /Users/armo/Code/origami/src/app/insights/insights.module.ts

*Attempt 2*

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import '../../assets/maps/world.js';
```

Runtime error

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined

Answer (score 1):

To load maps you could try with something like:

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highmaps';

// add your maps here as they will be added to Highcharts variable
...
imports: [
  ChartModule.forRoot(
    Highcharts
  ),
}
```

You are using `Highcharts.maps['custom/world']` so you should load [the file with map](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js). The file is JS script that adds to `Highcharts.maps` the map file that is later used in chart's config.

If there are problems with loading Highmaps you could try with [Highcharts + map module](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started). However, the [Angular2-highcharts using forRoot with modules applied internally](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts#add-highcharts-modules) to the Highcharts and without adding map module first there will not be Highcharts.maps, so you will not be able to load any maps - you could try with:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
require('highcharts/modules/map')(Highcharts);
// add maps here
...
imports: [
  ChartModule.forRoot(
    Highcharts // this will pass Highcharts with the map module and maps
  ),
}
```

Another option would be to replace `mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],` in series config with [content of the map file](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js).

**EDIT:**

Here's a demo for using Highmaps with angular2-highcharts: http://plnkr.co/edit/AmDfKwhRhshFn3CPprkk?p=preview

If you wan to load mapData from file I suggest loading it as a JSON data from GeoJSON files in [map collection](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/) or nest the JS map file with same code as modules have ([example](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-dist/blob/master/js/modules/no-data-to-display.src.js#L11-L17)):

```
(function(factory) {
    if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
        module.exports = factory;
    } else {
        factory(Highcharts);
    }
}(function(Highcharts) {
...
// map file here
...
}));
```

Next, you could load this as other modules - `require('./path-to-map/your-edited-map-file')' in 'forRoot'. You might need to set`allowJs`to`true`in`compilerOptions`in`tsconfig.json` on top level of your angular app.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your effort. Unfortunately none of the approaches made things work. I edited my post to include detailed output of my attempts.

Comment: I ended up pasting the json mapData (which I wanted to avoid), but it only allowed me to got rid of "Highcharts undefined" errors. I think that something basic went wrong on my side, `<chart type="Map"></chart>` that plunkr uses, does not work for me (unknown type). Lowercase "map" renders nothing. I think I will give a try to Leaflet. Thanks for your effort though!